# Pandas how to find length of an integer in column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a DataFrame, you can have it by run following code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
df = """
  contract      EndDate     
  A00118        12345678     
  A00118        123456   
  A00118        12345    
 
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(df.strip()), sep='\s+')
df
```

The output is:

```
contract    EndDate
0   A00118  12345678
1   A00118  123456
2   A00118  12345
```

How to apply this logic to it:
if the EndDate has only 6 digits ,then add 00 to then end of it,the output should be:

```
contract    EndDate
0   A00118  12345678
1   A00118  12345600
2   A00118  12345000
```

Any friend can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `str.ljust` to pad from the right side:

```
length = df['EndDate'].astype(str)
df['EndDate'] = length.str.ljust(length.str.len().max(), '0')
```

If you want `EndDate` to be int dtype, you can of course use `astype`:

```
df['EndDate'] = length.str.ljust(length.str.len().max(), '0').astype(int)
```

Output:

```
  contract   EndDate
0   A00118  12345678
1   A00118  12345600
2   A00118  12345000
```